# How will i make a percentSorted () method that will output 100.0 if sorted and if not 0.00?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] values = {12, 23, -5, 56, 32, 17, -4, -49, -1, -23, 45};
    int n = values.length; 

    System.out.println("Values: ");
    for (int val : values)
    System.out.println(val + ", ");
    
    System.out.println();
    
    if (isSorted(values))
    System.out.println("Is in order");
    else
    System.out.println("Is NOT in order\n");
    System.out.println("Numbers of integers that is out of order: " + countOut(values, n));
    }
    
}
```

This is the program i created and i am asked to make percentSorted() method to output 100.0 if the array elements is sorted and if not 0.00. Can someone suggest some methods?

Comment: How do you tell if an array is 50.0 sorted? Or 27.3 sorted? Generally, if an array is sorted ascending according its elements' natural order, subsequent elements will compare <=.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you asked for, just the two results 100.0 and 0.00 are required.
Loop over the array and compare each value with it's next value. If they are in wrong order return 0.00. If all compares worked ok, return 100.0.

If the result should not just be 0.00 and 100.0 as you asked for, you need to make up your mind what the percentage could mean. You could simply say "how many of the elements are in correct order" and return that value as percentage:

- So loop over the array and test each value to it's next, counting how many times the elements were correct.
  Finally return the amount of correct divided by the total number of elements.
- An alternative could be to create a copy of the array and sort it. Then loop over the elements and count how many elements of the first array match the same position in the sorted array.
  Finally return the count of correct positiions divided by the total number of elements.